# Identify Display Technology

Tags: lcd, display

Can somebody tell me what display technology this is? There're digits made out individual pixels and then there're glyphs. It is installed behind white plastic.

[image: Display]

Comment: What about that 'alarm' symbol? is it made of pixels ?

Comment: @nidhin No pixels there.

Comment: Then it would be LED display as BarsMonster said.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you also please take a look on the additional questions I posted as comment to his answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have never come across this. Try googling "custom LED displays".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be made exactly like 7-segment LED's: i.e. a bunch of LEDs with diffuser of the required form for each pixel.

I don't think it's OLED - all OLED's I've seen were dot-matrix.

Comment: I expected something like this. Do you now whether such matrices are available off the shelf for prototyping? In mass quantities such displays are quite cheep produce, aren't they?

Comment: Well, for prototyping you can just use discrete LED's and your imagination. Making diffuser prototype might be more complicated - 3D printed or something for example using 2-color 3D printer, neutral (which is somewhat transparent) and black.